# Некорректные столкновения unity3d (2d physics)

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть проблема с отскоком при столкновениях.
Квадраты - просто объекты с коллайдером (бокс 2д)
Шарик - твердое тело + коллайдер. Материал твердого тела с отскоком = 1, трение = 0

Черная стрелка - вектор падения на коллайдер.
Красная стрелками - вектор отскока(сейчас так и работает).
Зеленая стрелка - то что нужно мне получить.

Картинка слева - Квадраты это коллайдеры, примыкают плотно друг к другу, при столкновении с движущимся шариком - шарик не всегда отражается так как нужно. Что иногда приводит к тому что шарик может навсегда остаться летать между двух стенок из таких блоков.

Картинка справа - при малом угле падения на блок, или при низкой скорость шарика, он не отскакивает под тем же углом, а начинается катиться вдоль коллайдера

[image: Рисунок]

Comment: Настройки физ. материала в студию

Comment: Ссылка на тестовый проект http://dropmefiles.com/wpxeI 
Слева-направо по шарикам в проекте 
1) медленный шарик с низким углом - начинает почти скользить вдоль стены после столкновения.
2) маленький шарик в коридоре - посреди коридора начинает лететь в обратную сторону
3) большой шарик в коридоре - аналогично (2)
4) большой шарик - первый угол отскока примерно правильный, но при последующих столкновениях отскакивает назад как (2)

Comment: Прощу прощения, не тот проект загрузил вот верный http://dropmefiles.com/dsmm1